# spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.producer.configuration is not applied

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have a small application for stream data processing. I receive data from one topic, process and write to another. I use spring cloud and apache kafka for my java applicaton.
I want to set some properties for producer like bufferSize. Here is an example of my application.yaml

```js
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        point-output-channel:
          destination: DST4-topic
        point-input-channel:
          destination: SRC4-topic
      kafka:
        streams:
          bindings:
            point-output-channel:
              producer:
                bufferSize: 14000
          binder:
            brokers:  localhost:9092
            configuration:
              commit.interval.ms: 10000
              state.dir: state-store
              default:
                key:
                  serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                value:
                  serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
```

But the bufferSize value is not applied to the producer, what could be wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-producer-properties) it seems like your config is slightly wrong. Kafka bindings properties should be `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.producer` not `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.<channelName>.producer`

Try this instead:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        point-output-channel:
          destination: DST4-topic
        point-input-channel:
          destination: SRC4-topic
      kafka:
        bindings:
          point-output-channel:
            producer:
              bufferSize: 14000
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
          configuration:
            commit.interval.ms: 10000
            state.dir: state-store
            default:
              key:
                serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
              value:
                serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
```